# Error in c# programming

Tags: c#

Hi could someone please help me in my program it contains the following errors: 
in line (3,26) it displays "{ expected"
in line (5,22) it displays "{ expected"
and lastly in line (5,22) it displays "invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration".

I really can't determine how to fix the error since I just started to program c#. Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks!

```
using System;

namespace GradeEvaluation;
{
    public class Program;
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            int grade, finalGrade;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your final grade: ");
            finalGrade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if(finalGrade >= 0 && finalGrade <= 59.9)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 5", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 60 && finalGrade <= 63.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 3", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 64 && finalGrade <= 67.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 2.75", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 68 && finalGrade <= 71.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 2.5", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 72 && finalGrade <= 75.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 2.25", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 76 && finalGrade <= 79.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 2", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 80 && finalGrade <= 83.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 1.75", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 84 && finalGrade <= 87.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 1.5", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 88 && finalGrade <= 91.99)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 1.25", name);
            else if(finalGrade >= 92 && finalGrade <= 100)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Your final transmuted grade is 1", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be so nice if people read error messages before posting on SO. _sigh_

Comment: The error "invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" sums up your problem quit nicely

Answer (score 5):

Remove these semicolons (`;`):

```
namespace GradeEvaluation;
{
    public class Program;
    {
```

**Compiler errors are your friend!**

Reading the error messages will often provide incredible insight to the problem:

[image]

Line 3, column 26 is where your first incorrect semicolon is: `namespace GradeEvaluation;` The compiler is telling you "No, I'm expecting a `{` here, not whatever you have!"

Line 5, column 25 is even *more* explicit! (`public class Program;`) It's telling you that you've provided an invalid token (`;`), and again, it's expecting a `{`.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `;` after your namespace and class names:

```
namespace GradeEvaluation
{
    public class Program
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the semi colons from

```
namespace GradeEvaluation;
{
    public class Program;
```

so, something like

```
namespace GradeEvaluation
{
    public class Program
```

Comment: I just have to ask: as a user with 72k rep, what exactly is your rationale for providing an answer that only duplicates what is already there (twice, in this case), other than for milking additional rep?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, if you wish to me to remove my answer, then just say so. Id gladly remove it for you.

Comment: I don't care - I just really don't understand the point in adding an answer that says exactly what the answers that already exist say.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart - I don't think your assertion is fair or correct.  The time stamps on all three answers are so close, what does it matter?  If a user who sees these - like I just did - wants to up vote all the answers - again, like I just did - it is up to them.  And, more to the point, I LIKE having multiple (even exact) answers to questions because it gives the person a choice to pick the answer that most speaks to their need.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart IMHO, questions about syntax errors are off-topic, because they don't have any evidence that OP has minimal understanding of problem, thus no answer should be given and question must be closed/marked as duplicate altogether.